# Cannot create database with pouchdb in couchdb

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

while trying to just create a database with pouchDB for couchDB, the following error is thrown:

```
{"error":"not_found","reason":"Database does not exist."}.
```

My code to create a test db is as simple as this:

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/testdb');
```

Also, the couchDB server is running and reachable at http://localhost:5984/ and it says:

```
{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"2.1.1","features":["scheduler"],"vendor":{"name":"The Apache Software Foundation"}}
```

I have even enabled CORS for couchDB.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [PouchDB API](https://pouchdb.com/guides/databases.html#remote-databases) (especially the info block), it doesn't automatically create the database by creating a new PouchDB object.

You need to call an API function of the database in order to create the database.
For example, you could create your PouchDB object and then call db.info() to create the database.